# Show popup in Infopath 2013 without custom code

Tags: infopath

I have a button in InfoPath form.

I'm trying to write a rule to show popup on button click.

how to achieve this without any custom code?

Comment: create new view.You show new view, on button click
.add values on that view. and also add close button on new view.
 You can find create new view option in Info path form designer inside Page Design ribbon